# Print the input search string if grep doesn't match

Tags: search, awk, grep

I have file1

```
BOB
JOHN
SALLY
```

I have file2

```
There was a boy called JOHN and he was playing with FRED while
JILL went off to find a bucket of water from TOM but she
fell down the hill.
```

I want to iterate through the file1 words and search for these in file2.
I want to print the words that are NOT found in file2.

So the output would be

```
BOB
SALLY
```

I guess it is if the grep fails, I'd like to print the string that grep was searching for.

I'm starting here:

```
grep -o -f file1 file2
```

But of course, this returns

```
JOHN
```

How would I get the original search strings that didn't match - to print instead?

Comment: Should `JOHN` in file1 match `JOHNSON` in file2 or not? You're getting answers making different assumptions about that. [edit] your question to include an example of a partial match like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a `grep` one liner to get this done:

```sh
grep -vxFf <(tr '[[:blank:]]' '\n' < file2) file1

BOB
SALLY
```

Using `tr` to convert space/tab to newline first then using `grep -vxFf` to get non-matching words in `file1`.

Or as David suggested in comments below:

```sh
grep -vxFf <(printf '%s\n' $(<file2)) file1
```

Comment: Okay, that rocks. I thought down the line of process substitution, but couldn't pull it off. `tr` was the key. Good form.

Comment: `grep -vxFf <(printf "%s\n" $(< file2)) file1` Shorter `:)`

Comment: Wow, such elegant solutions, they increase my learnings for these powerful tools, thank you @anubhava and DavidC.Rankin !

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
{
  for(i in arr){
    if(index($0,i)){
      delete arr[i]
      next
    }
  }
}
END{
  for(i in arr){
    print i
  }
}
' file1 file2
```

Comment: Now you are rocking.

Answer (score 3):

If the order isn't critical, you can use:

```
awk '
    FNR == NR { a[$1]=0; next } 
    { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if ($i in a)
            a[$i]++
    }
    END { 
        for (i in a)
            if (!a[i])
                print i 
    }
' file1 file2
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '
>     FNR == NR { a[$1]=0; next }
>     { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
>         if ($i in a)
>             a[$i]++
>     }
>     END {
>         for (i in a)
>             if (!a[i])
>                 print i
>     }
> ' file1 file2
SALLY
BOB
```

Comment: `delete` is a clean way to go -- liked that too.

Comment: Cool, both of you have working awk solutions

Comment: The `awk` solutions in this case pale in comparison to the concise `grep` solution. You got my vote.